# How can I get the _id from a single document using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to query for a document with a given condition and have it return the `_id` for that document. Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```js
User.find(
    {phone: phone},
    null,
    {},
    function (err, data) {
        user_id = data._id;
    }
);
```

Basically, I'm trying to query the Users collection for a user/document with a certain phone number, and then have it return the `_id` for that user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result of `.find()` is a cursor not a document. If you expect only one result then use `.findOne()` which returns a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find only one document you need to use [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne):

```
User.findOne({phone : phone}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    user_id = data._id;
});
```

If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk.

If you want to get multiple documents you need to use `find` and your `data` parameter will then contain all users that matches your criteria.